# Autolayout in IB: adding constraint related to a second view

Tags: ios, xcode5, interface-builder, autolayout

Short question: I'd like to add two constraints, so a textview always stays below both of two other labels. I'd like to do this via Interface Builder.

Longer explanation. This is my screen:
[image]

The "Lorem ipsum" text currently has a constraint that lets it stay 8 px below the red "MAR-14" label. I'd like to add a second, lower priority constraint that lets it stay 8 px below the location label ("Amsterdam, Netherlands") as well. How can I add this constraint easily in Interface Builder?

Comment: Why do you need two constraints?  Why not just one constraint  on the vertical spacing between “MAR-14” and “Lorem Ipsum”?

Comment: Sometimes the location becomes a multiline affair. A single constraint wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a second constraint pretty much just like you added the first constraint. You can Control-drag from one view to the other and select the Vertical Spacing constraint.

At first, this new constraint will be at priority 1000 (required) and will use the current distance from the canvas. You can select the new constraint and adjust those attributes.

How do you expect these two constraints to work in practice, though? What result do you want? Since the first constraint to the "MAR-14" label is at 1000 priority and specifies "equal" (rather than an inequality), the distance determines the spacing, period. A lower priority constraint will never matter.

If you want the Lorem ipsum to be a certain distance from *the lower of the two*, then you would need a few constraints. One saying the top of Lopem ipsum is greater than or equal to the bottom of MAR-14 plus 8. Another saying the top of Lorem ipsum is greater than or equal to the bottom of Amsterdam plus however much. And then a third saying it should be as close as possible to the top of the superview: the top of Lorem ipsum is equal to the top of the superview. You set the priority of this last one to be lower than required, but probably still pretty high. However, you want it lower than the vertical compression resistance priorities of the views in between. 740 might be good.

Comment: Awesome, I first didn't understand the popup that the Control-drag gave me. And yes, your last suggestion about three constraints is correct, that's the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your problem correctly than you need to set 2 Top constrain for TextView

```
1. Relavent to date label/button
2. with location  label but with low priority
```

You can add same way constraint with location  label than double click on constrain on right side of screen in property window you will see priority reduce priority as you want default 1000 high priority (reduce to 800 or as you want).

Or after seeting constrain on property window right side  you will see constrain as your screen shot display click on tool icon you will get edit option go to priority filed and reduce for 1000 to set low priority.

So it will set low priority constrain 4 you.

hope this will help you